# $N$ commuting vector fields on an $N$-dimensional compact manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

If an $N$-dimensional compact manifold has $N$ commuting vector fields, does this mean the manifold is actually a torus?

Comment: Do you demand that the vector fields are pointwise linearly independent?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true (if the manifold is assumed connected; otherwise you could have a disjoint union of tori). This is an exercise on page 116 of *Differentiable Manifolds: A First Course* by Lawrence Conlon. A proof can be found in the paper [Integrably parallelizable manifolds](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-035-02/S0002-9939-1972-0305296-5) by Vagn Lundsgaard Hansen (Lemma 2), which is in free access. The author doesn't define "rank" there, but it's understood as the maximal number of linearly independent commuting vector fields.